# Selenium: Find only visible elements by ClassName - Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, element

I have a couple of elements of the same class in a single page, and I would like to move to each one of them and then do some stuff with it.

I know how to get there(to the element), but I don't know how to access only the element that is seen.
Any help ?

Comment: we are having a method named isDisplayed(). If it returns true, that means the element is not hidden and visible to enduser

Comment: That's not what im looking for. I have lots of element of the same class in a single page, how can I access them one by one with scrolling ?

Comment: I guess, isDisplayed will return true, even when the element is not in view but visible if scrolled

Comment: That is correct, I just need a way to get the elements from a certain point, because it always gives me the elements that starts and the top of the page

Comment: list<webElements> all = driver.findElements(by.className("name")); Now all has the webelements with same class.

Comment: Not exactly, that is what Im doing, but the elements that are too far down cant be reached so it gives me just some of the elements and I would like to scroll down and get the rest. Ideas ?

Comment: Too far down can't be reached. Is this kind of Ajax/angular application or in normal HTML findelements is returning only the elements from current view?

Comment: Just normal HTML. basically, I checked and I need code for findElement by classname that will give me only the displayed elements.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I have the following 2 suggested ways:

1. You can use isDisplayed() as below:

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.id("idOfElement")).isDisplayed();
   ```
2. You can define a method as shown below and call it:

   ```
   public boolean isElementPresent(By by)
   {
    try 
    {
     driver.findElement(by);
     return true;
    }
    catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e)
    {
     return false;
    }
   }
   ```

   Now, you can use assertion as below to check whether the element is present or not:

   ```
   assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("idOfElement")));
   ```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: That's not what im looking for. I have lots of element of the same class in  a single page, how can I access them one by one with scrolling ?

Comment: In most of the cases, all elements will be visible. In a rare case, we can have elements with same attribute one with hidden and other with visible.

Comment: The element are not visible because I need to scroll down. But when I scroll down and look for the elements again - it gives me the same elements as before and not from the point Im at ATM.